# How to inform Foreign office about Leaving Germany (Currently Working on a Blue Card)

Tags: germany, blue-card, non-residents

I am a Non-EU citizen and I am working in Germany for around 1 year 11 Months now. Now due to some personal reasons, I am leaving Germany. I have started with the De-Registration process (Abmeldung), but I have heard that I also have to inform the Foreign office(ausländerbehörde) as I have not completed 2 years on Blue Card. I tried to find information on Google regarding this but couldn't find anything concrete. If anyone has experience or been in a similar situation, it would be really great if you could share your experience. I am currently based in Hamburg.

I looked into a similar question [How to inform foreign office in Germany regarding Blue card when leaving Germany?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8467/how-to-inform-foreign-office-in-germany-regarding-blue-card-when-leaving-germany) but couldn't find anything the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no requirement to also deregister by the foreigners office.

Important is only to deregister by the registry office.

After deregistration, a simple letter informing them of the fact would be sufficient.

Otherwise they would simply look into the registry and see that you have left should they become curious to what happened to you.

See also [How to apply for a Versicherungsverlauf](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19380/17166), which may be usefull for the future.

Comment: Hey @Mark Johnson Thanks for your reply. So what I understood is once I complete the Abmeldung then I would just send a copy of the feedback receipt to Ausländerbehörde over email and that's it.

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes. I have just added a link to another answer that you should read about getting a **Versicherungsverlauf**.